# Makefile with visual studio online

Tags: makefile, azure-devops

I just started messing with visual studio online, because I like the idea of not having to wait for 3 minutes while my laptop builds my program. However, I prefer to use makefiles for building my programs over any use of visual studio tools. Is there any way I can use a makefile to build my program on visual studio online?

Additionally, I use gnu make to build my program right now, and I would prefer to continue using it, as it is really easy to find examples and help using it. I don't like MSbuild, because it has a completely different syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Cant you just call your make utility from an automated build?

Builds in TFS and VSO currently use the same system. They user MSBuild to compile (make) the solution so the out of box make stem is MSBuild. If you want to replace that with your own make system then you need only download the .xaml build template and customise it to use that other system.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647551.aspx

In TFS 2015, and coming in VSO, is a new build system that would make this easyer.

Comment: The instructions are for use with visual studio, which I really don't like to use I find it bloated and slow compared to using  VI and the terminal. Is there any way I can set this up with out using visual studio and just editing a couple of files.